# Reg: Putty SSH Access

Tags: ssh, putty, linux-server

I have a Linux based virtual server recently purchased.

I need to transfer the files from local computer to my virtual server... I tried downloading the Putty. But there were no EXE files to install. i am using Windows XP at home. If possible, can i have to installer link.

Do we need to know Linux compulsorily for using this Putty.

And also is there any other tool which can be used by users who dont know linux commands.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

If its just for file transfer, you can use WinSCP to transfer files from your windows machine to your Linux machine via SSH.

Putty is a very simple application and does not require an installer. The putty application itself is all that's needed. I would suggest that if you're looking for some sort of web-hosting, you try to use a managed service if you're not familiar with how to access your console.